# Find minimum and maximum of $x^2 - 2x - y$ where $2x+3y \le 6, 2x+y \le 4; x,y \ge 0$

Tags: inequality

Find minimum and maximum of $x^2 - 2x - y$ where $2x+3y \le 6, 2x+y \le 4; x,y \ge 0$

---

I am very bad with inequalities, please help

Comment: Do you allow Lagrange multiplier?

Comment: @Cameron Buie I am in 9th grade, I don't know much calculus;
I don't like to use  Lagrange multiplier

Comment: @Inceptio: Based on several of your comments, lately, you are either psychic, or possessed of some source of information to which I have no access. Kudos, either way.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Hah! Nothing like that. I was just trying to tell that why use calculus, when it is rather easy to use simple high school math?

Comment: @Inceptio: When you get accustomed enough to using a hammer, everything starts to look like a nail.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Well, yeah.. I can not make my point here. Anyway, peace. Lets think of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $x^2-2x-y=(x-1)^2-y-1$. Then consider the parabola $y=(x-1)^2-1$ and draw area of all the restricted conditions.

Comment: (+1): An excellent example of where less advanced mathematical machinery can make things easier than the more advanced sort!

Answer (score 2):

Below is a graphical solution to the problem. Note that $$f(x,y) = x^2-2x-y = c$$ is a parabola and our goal is to find the maximum $c$ possible.[image]

The blue color region is the feasible region obtained using the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the region.  For the maximum, for any fixed $x$, we should pick $y$ as small as possible. This is $0$.  Now we should pick $x$ as far from $1$ as possible. That's easy to pick out.

The minimum may be more complicated. The two interesting constraint lines meet at $(1.2)$. So from $x=0$ to $x=1$, the best choice of $y$ is from $2x+3y=6$. From $x=1$ to $x=3$ the best choice is from $2x+y=4$. On each interval, we then have a quadratic minimization problem.